# Hibernate, Only one row is being saved from one to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two entities:-

**Sales.Java**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int salesId;
    private BigDecimal discount;
    private BigDecimal totalTransaction;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sales", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductSalesDetails> productSalesDetails = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<ProductSalesDetails> getProductSalesDetails() {
        return productSalesDetails;
    }

    public void addProductSalesDetails(ProductSalesDetails productSalesDetails) {
        this.productSalesDetails.add(productSalesDetails);
    }
```

and another entity is:-

**ProductSalesDetails.java**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String category,name,vendor;

    private int  quantity;
    private BigDecimal price;

    private BigDecimal totalSalesAmount;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createdDate;

    private String salesBy;

    @ManyToOne
    private Sales sales;
```

now my form data from front end is JSON which looks like:-

```
[{category:"spa"
discount:""
grandTotal:3800
name:"toe cleaner"
price:"1200"
quantity:2
totalPrice:2400
vendor:"spa product"},
{category:"Hair"
discount:""
grandTotal:3800
name:"hair wash shampoo"
price:"700"
quantity:2
totalPrice:1400
vendor:"hair vendor"}]
```

My DAO Class:-

```
public void createBill(List<ProductSales> salesList) {

        Sales s = new Sales();
        ProductSalesDetails ps = new ProductSalesDetails();

        for (ProductSales p : salesList){
            RgProduct rgProduct = productDao
.getSingleProductByProductName(p.getName());

            s.setDiscount(p.getDiscount());
            s.setTotalTransaction(p.getGrandTotal());

            ps.setCategory(p.getCategory());
            ps.setName(p.getName());
            ps.setQuantity(p.getQuantity());
            ps.setVendor(p.getVendor());
            ps.setPrice(rgProduct.getCostPrice());
            ps.setTotalSalesAmount(p.getTotalPrice());
            ps.setCreatedDate(new Date());
            ps.setSalesBy("sagar");

            s.addProductSalesDetails(ps);
            ps.setSales(s);

        }
        em.persist(s);

        for(ProductSalesDetails pds : s.getProductSalesDetails()){
            em.persist(pds);
        }
}
```

so now i am trying to save grandtotal and discount in sales table while other details should be saved on ProductSalesDetails table. i am trying to put the relation between sales and ProductSalesDetails.

ProductSalesDetails will have one foreign key column which will be mapped to primary key of sales table.

my ideal database rows will look like:-

**Sales Table**
[image]

and Product Details table:-
[image]

currently, sales table is being saved as required but on product details table only one row is saved no matter how many rows exist in the list.